# Check which radio option is selected and display a button based on that

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form, which contains a free option and a paid option.

If the user selects a paid option, I want to display a different button than if they press the free option.

form:

```
<form method=POST>
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required="required"> 1 day (free) &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" required="required"> 7 days  (£12.99)</p>
    <button type="submit" class="link button" display:block">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

What I want is something like:

```
  <form method=POST>
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required="required"> 1 day (free) &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" required="required"> 7 days  ($12.99)</p>
     // if radio value == "7days":
     <button type="submit" display:block">Pay 12.99 now </button>
     // else:
     <button type="submit" display:block">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

I am not sure how to achieve this in real time while the user is completing the form, I'm assuming its Javascript, but im not sure how to implement? Thanks.

EDIT:

The `12.99` button will take the person to a payment handler, whereas the other one should just complete/submit the form.

EDIT2:

This is the payment processor that I use:

```
<form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="{{ key }}"
          data-description="Website Purchase"
          data-currency=usd
          data-amount="{{ price }}"
          data-locale="auto"></script>

    <button type="submit" class="link button" style="margin:auto;">COMPLETE THIS ORDER</button>
</form>
```

So really I will have to replace the `pay 12.99` button with the above form

Comment: Given that the only difference is the text - and not the functionality - why not simply amend the text of the button?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica sorry I abbreviated my actual code to make my question easier to understand. There is different functionality, the payment button will go to a payment handler whereas the free wont.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica but I need to display a different button for each option to do this, unless there is a better way? I'm v new to Js

Comment: are you open with jquery solution ?

Comment: @Swati yes please

Comment: @jim: could you share how the HTML is different in the `<button>` elements, or the `<form>`, that shows how the payment-processor is accessed or bypassed? Is there an attribute or property change? I've offered *an* answer, but I feel it's not the best answer it could be as yet.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica thank you, I have added the form that needs to be submitted for payment processing.

Comment: Having looked at that information, @jim, I stand corrected; I don't think there's any easy way of updating the script, or `<button>`, approach you're using (beyond the hiding/showing). Possibly it might work if the `<button>` element's classes were toggled/updated, but I don't know whether the Stripe JS would tolerate that. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: changed my answer with your update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply :

no need to have several buttons doing the same thing, you can directly change the text

no need to repeat the required attribute on all radio buttons just on the first one is sufficient

use the labels for the radio inputs, this makes them active to act on the radio, it's the same for the checkboxes

all the elements of a form have a hierarchical link with their form, use their name, as in a json system to access it directly, without needing to use a direct identifier (as here for myForm.btSubmit and myForm.plan )

```js
const 
  myForm  = document.getElementById('my-form')
, day7    = '7days'  

myForm.oninput = evt =>
  {
  if (evt.target.name == 'plan')
    {
    myForm.btSubmit.removeAttribute('style')
    myForm.btSubmit.textContent = (myForm.plan.value === day7) ? 'Pay 12.99 now' : 'Submit'
    }
  }

myForm.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault()  // disable submit  ?for testing
  if (myForm.plan.value === day7 )  
    {
    // do special stuf for this case
    console.clear()
    console.log('7 days case')
    }
  else
    {
    // do normal stuff for other case
    console.clear()
    console.log('not 7 days case')
    }
  }
```

```css
label, button { 
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : both;
  margin  : .5em;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="my-form" >
  <label> <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required > 1 day (free) &nbsp; </label>  
  <label> <input type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" > 7 days  ($12.99)</label>  

  <button type="submit" name="btSubmit" style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that directly in the onclick function:

```
  <form method=POST>
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required="required" onclick="document.getElementById('s2').style.display ='none';document.getElementById('s1').style.display =''"> 1 day (free) &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" required="required" onclick="document.getElementById('s1').style.display ='none';document.getElementById('s2').style.display =''"> 7 days  ($12.99)</p>
     <button type="submit" display:block" id='s1'>Pay 12.99 now </button>
     <button type="submit" display:block" id='s2'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Stop polluting HTML markup with on* handlers, same as you hopefully don't use inline style attributes. JS and CSS should be in one place only, and that's their respective files or tags.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:
you can use "checked" selector in css

```
<form method=POST>
    <input class="free-option" type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required="required"> 1 day (free) &nbsp;
    <input class="paid-option" type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" required="required"> 7 days  ($12.99)</p>
     // if radio value == "7days":
     <button class="paid-btn" type="submit" display:block">Pay 12.99 now </button>
     // else:
     <button class="free-btn" type="submit" display:block">Submit</button>
 </form>

<style>
.free-option:checked, .free-btn {
   display: inline;
}
.paid-option:checked, .paid-btn {
   display: inline;
}
}
</style>
```

when ".free-option" checked, apply styles on ".free-btn" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible approach – albeit using plain JavaScript in place of jQuery – is the following. Please note that I've added a `data-plan` custom `data-*` attribute to each of the `<button>` elements which is equal to the `value` of the relevant `<input>` elements.

I've also wrapped the `<input>` elements in a `<label>`, in order to associate the explanatory text with the relevant `<input>`, which allows clicking on the text to check the relevant `<input>`:

```js
// a named function to handle the toggling, we're
// using an Arrow function (since we have no need to use
// or update the 'this' within the function), and passing
// in the Event Object, which is supplied automatically
// by EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
const toggleButton = (event) => {

  // the <input> that fires the 'change' event (see the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() call later) is the
  // event.target, so here we get a reference to that
  // changed <input>:
  let changed = event.target,
      // interactive form elements (<input>, <select>,
      // <button>...) all have a form property which
      // identifies the <form> element they belong to;
      // we use that to find all <button> elements
      // within the same <form>:
      buttons = changed.form.querySelectorAll('button');

  // we then iterate over that NodeList using
  // NodeList.prototype.forEach(), using an anonymous
  // (unnamed) Arrow function expression:
  buttons.forEach(
    // the 'button' argument is a reference to the current
    // Node of the NodeList over which we're iterating;
    // here we use a conditional operator (ternary) to
    // update the display of the current <button> node.
    // If the buttons 'data-plan' attribute is exactly
    // equal to the changed <input> element's 'value'
    // property/attribute then we set the display to
    // 'initial', otherwise if not an exact match we
    // return 'none':
    (button) => button.style.display = button.dataset.plan === changed.value ? 'initial' : 'none'
  );
}

// here we bind an anonymous function to the 'DOMContentLoaded'
// event of the Window Object:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // we get the <form> element:
  const form = document.querySelector('form'),
      // we retrieve the <input type="radio"> elements
      // within the <form>:
      radios = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  // and use an anonymous arrow function as the callback,
  // here we iterate over each <input> and bind the
  // toggleButton() function (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses) as the 'change' event-handler:
  radios.forEach(
    (el) => el.addEventListener('change', toggleButton)
  );
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <!-- wrapping each <input> with a <label> to improve user experience -->
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1days" required="required"> 1 day (free)
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="plan" value="7days" required="required"> 7 days ($12.99)
  </label>
  <!-- if radio value == "7days"; also we add the custom data-plan
       attribute to reflect the value of the relevant <input>: -->
  <button data-plan="7days" type="submit">Pay 12.99 now </button>
  <!-- else: -->
  <button data-plan="1days" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form method=POST>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-seven" name="plan" value="7days" required="required"> 7 days  (£12.99)
        <input type="radio" id="radio-one" name="plan" value="1days" required="required"> 1 day (free) &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit" class="link button" display:block">
     </form>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
         $('#radio-one').click(()=>{
            // $('#btn').prop('value',$('#radio-one').val())
            /* or like this */
            $('#btn').prop('value','Submit')
         })
         $('#radio-seven').click(()=>{
            // $('#btn').prop('value',$('#radio-seven').val())
            /* or like this */
            $('#btn').prop('value','Pay 12.99 now')
         })
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i have used Jquery-library :)

Comment: Please provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.